# VB6 - Defining a String Array

Tags: arrays, syntax, vb6

I need to use VB6 and I'm struggling with a few basic tasks.

When I define an array in C# for example:

```
string[] s = {"a", "b", "c", "d" };
```

But in VB6, I've been doing this:

```
Dim s(0 To 3) As String
s(0) = "a"
s(1) = "b"
s(2) = "c"
s(3) = "d"
```

Is there a more efficient way of defining an array in VB6 than the example I illustrated above? A way similar to the C# approach?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Dim s
s = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Comment: Simple enough, surprising I couldn't find that anywhere haha.
Thanks!

Comment: It should be emphasised that this is an array of *Variants* not  *Strings*

Answer (score 12):

If you want a *String* array as opposed to the *Variant* array `Array()` will yield;

```
Function ArrayString(ParamArray tokens()) As String()
    ReDim arr(UBound(tokens)) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
        arr(i) = tokens(i)
    Next
    ArrayString = arr
End Function

...

Dim a() As String
a = ArrayString("foo", "bar", ..., "qux")
```

Comment: very interesting

Answer (score 11):

Here's another possibility:

```
Dim S() As String

S = Split("a|b|c|d", "|")
```

Comment: This isn't amazingly efficient. The Split() function returns a Variant containing an array of String, and then it copies the entire array into a new array of String.

Comment: It isn't an amazingly poor performer.  If you need to recreate the array within a tight loop you can create an array this way outside the loop and then copy it into a second array variable inside the loop for each iteration.