# insert multiple values into an array in VB 6.0

Tags: arrays, vb6

I need to insert unique values once into an array without looping like below statement(I'm using visual basic 6.0)

```
Dim Marks(0 To 9) As Integer = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,}
```

but it has got compile error. how should be changed above statement ??

Comment: Short answer: VB6 doesn't do array literals. Longer answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17443632/vb6-defining-a-string-array (yes its for strings, but you can see how it would apply to ints)

Answer (score 2):

From [Alex K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17445917/123723), but converted to int:

```
Function ArrayInt(ParamArray tokens()) As Integer()
    ReDim arr(UBound(tokens)) As Integer
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
        arr(i) = tokens(i)
    Next
    ArrayInt = arr
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim Marks() As Integer
Marks = ArrayInt(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the easier way that I could found

```
Dim marks 
marks = Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Comment: That doesn't actually do what you want (quite). The function `array()` returns an array of variants. And by declaring (`dim`) marks with no type at all, you have declared it as a variant itself. This leaves you vulnerable to a whole load of problems in your code, as it is possible that that marks will not be an array at all, or that it may contain values that are not integers. At the very least, declare `dim marks as variant()`